# Is there any complete real life Rails project with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm learning RSpec for a while and reading some articles, books and other resources. But I wonder if is there any complete real life Rails project, that using RSpec, with source codes available to examine. I study some gems and Ruby projects but still I think it would be better to see a Rails project's source code in action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse) is a large, real world project you could take a look at.

They use RSpec and you can view all their testing code [here](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/tree/master/spec).

Answer (score 0):

Another huge open source rails app using rspec is spree commerce https://github.com/spree/spree